# Outlook Add-in/plug-in to find email

Tags: outlook

I am currently using Outlook 2016 as part of O365.  Outlook is fairly configurable, but only in the parts of the program that Microsoft is actually working on.  Other parts have not been updated since Outlook 2003, like the Advanced Find dialog.  You can't save the settings, the window usually draws incorrectly, and it's pretty frustrating to have to resize the window and the columns all the time.

I'd like a replacement for the advanced find dialog in Outlook.  You can bring up the advanced find with CTRL + SHIFT + F.  It looks like this:

[image] (c/o DDG search: [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hub/2011/03/11/find-that-mail-with-outlook-advanced-search-options/))

I came across an older add-in called Lookout, but according to the review, doesn't work with Outlook 2007 or later.

I would prefer the add-in to be free or low cost (